# Crash when trying to change the TargetArmLength (Unreal Engine C++)

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

It crashes anytime I'm trying to change `SpringArmComponent->TargetArmLength`,
even if I do this: `UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%f"), SpringArmComponent->TargetArmLength);`

What am I doing wrong?

It crashes in the `ZoomIn()` and `ZoomOut()` functions, but it works in the constructor. If I do only `SpringArmComponent->TargetArmLength` it won't crash, but it does if I try to log it.

**.h file fragment:**

```cpp
class UCameraComponent;
class USpringArmComponent;

UCLASS()
class WELT_API ATPWBaseCharacter : public ACharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Camera", meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
    UCameraComponent* CameraComponent;

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Camera", meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
    USpringArmComponent* SpringArmComponent;

public:
    // Sets default values for this character's properties
    ATPWBaseCharacter(const FObjectInitializer& ObjInit);

protected:
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "Movement")
    bool IsRunning() const;

private:
    bool WantsToRun = false;
    bool IsMovingForward = false;

    void MoveForward(float Amount);
    void MoveRight(float Amount);

    void OnStartRunning();
    void OnStopRunning();

    void LookUp(float Amount);
    void TurnAround(float Amount);
    
    void ChangeCameraLen(bool bAmount);

public:
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "Movement")
    void ZoomIn();
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "Movement")
    void ZoomOut();
};
```

**.cpp file fragment:**

```cpp
ATPWBaseCharacter::ATPWBaseCharacter(const FObjectInitializer& ObjInit) : 
    Super(ObjInit.SetDefaultSubobjectClass<UTPWCharacterMovementComponent>(ACharacter::CharacterMovementComponentName))
{
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    SpringArmComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USpringArmComponent>(TEXT("SpringArmComponent"));
    SpringArmComponent->SetupAttachment(GetRootComponent());
    // SpringArmComponent->SocketOffset.Set(0, 0, 80);
    SpringArmComponent->TargetArmLength = 400.0f;
    SpringArmComponent->bUsePawnControlRotation = true;

    CameraComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("CameraComponent"));
    CameraComponent->SetupAttachment(SpringArmComponent, USpringArmComponent::SocketName);
    CameraComponent->bUsePawnControlRotation = false;

    bUseControllerRotationPitch = false;
    bUseControllerRotationYaw = false;
    bUseControllerRotationRoll = false;
}
void ATPWBaseCharacter::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
}
void ATPWBaseCharacter::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

    // AddActorLocalRotation(QuatRotation, false, 0, ETeleportType::None);
    FRotator NewRotationVector = FRotator(0.0f, GetVelocity().Rotation().Yaw, 0.0f);    // pitch, yaw, roll
    if (!NewRotationVector.IsZero())
    {
        FRotator NewRotation = FRotator(NewRotationVector);
        FQuat QuatRotation = FQuat(NewRotation);
        SetActorRotation(QuatRotation, ETeleportType::None);
    }
}
void ATPWBaseCharacter::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveForward", this, &ATPWBaseCharacter::MoveForward);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveRight", this, &ATPWBaseCharacter::MoveRight);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("LookUp", this, &ATPWBaseCharacter::LookUp);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("TurnAround", this, &ATPWBaseCharacter::TurnAround);

    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("WheelUp", IE_Pressed, this, &ATPWBaseCharacter::ZoomIn);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("WheelDown", IE_Pressed, this, &ATPWBaseCharacter::ZoomOut);

    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Jump", IE_Pressed, this, &ATPWBaseCharacter::Jump);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Run", IE_Pressed, this, &ATPWBaseCharacter::OnStartRunning);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Run", IE_Released, this, &ATPWBaseCharacter::OnStopRunning);
}

void ATPWBaseCharacter::MoveForward(float Amount)
{
    IsMovingForward = Amount > 0.0f;
    // AddMovementInput(GetActorForwardVector(), Amount);
    if ((Controller != nullptr) && (Amount != 0.0f))
    {
        const FRotator Rotation = Controller->GetControlRotation();
        const FRotator YawRotation(0, Rotation.Yaw, 0);
        const FVector Direction = FRotationMatrix(YawRotation).GetUnitAxis(EAxis::X);
        AddMovementInput(Direction, Amount);
    }
}

void ATPWBaseCharacter::MoveRight(float Amount)
{
    // AddMovementInput(GetActorRightVector(), Amount);
    if ((Controller != nullptr) && (Amount != 0.0f))

        const FRotator Rotation = Controller->GetControlRotation();
        const FRotator YawRotation(0, Rotation.Yaw, 0);
        const FVector Direction = FRotationMatrix(YawRotation).GetUnitAxis(EAxis::Y);
        AddMovementInput(Direction, Amount);
    }
}

void ATPWBaseCharacter::LookUp(float Amount)
{
    AddControllerPitchInput(Amount);
}

void ATPWBaseCharacter::TurnAround(float Amount)
{
    AddControllerYawInput(Amount);
}

void ATPWBaseCharacter::OnStartRunning()
{
    WantsToRun = true;
}
void ATPWBaseCharacter::OnStopRunning()
{
    WantsToRun = false;
}

void ATPWBaseCharacter::ZoomIn()
{
    // SpringArmComponent->TargetArmLength;
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%f"), SpringArmComponent->TargetArmLength);
    SpringArmComponent->TargetArmLength = 200.0f;
    // UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%f"), SpringArmComponent->TargetArmLength);
    // SpringArmComponent->SocketOffset = FVector(0, 0, 80);
}

void ATPWBaseCharacter::ZoomOut()
{
    // SpringArmComponent->TargetArmLength;
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%f"), SpringArmComponent->TargetArmLength);
    
    SpringArmComponent->SocketOffset = FVector(0, 0, 80);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug (using a debugger probably available as built-in feature in Unreal Engine 4) the code and see what message does it throw when it crashes?

Comment: @Jejo thank you, but if its null, why?

Comment: Where is `LogTemp` defined? Are you sure `SpringArmComponent` causes the crash, can it be `LogTemp`?

Comment: @Jejo ive done this `if (SpringArmComponent->IsValidLowLevel())
 {
  UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%f"), SpringArmComponent->TargetArmLength);
 }` and it dont crush, because its not valid, but whyyy

Comment: im sure, LogTemp is Unreal feature. and SpringArmComponent->TargetArmLength = 400.0f; doesnt work. I've checked it for validation and SpringArmComponent returns NULL, its weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any chance that you are running this in a Blueprint actor that derives from this class?  If so I've noticed that this can cause issues with component creation and will cause the engine to crash and return NULL for the component that is otherwise being set up properly.

I would suggest maybe trying to create a new derived class and see if that works.  I know it's a strange suggestion but it worked for me.